# Display Malformed HTML "Safely?"

Tags: html

Let's say I have some HTML like this:

```
<ol><li>a knock at the door, I'll be back in a second
```

which I display as inline HTML within a div that I produce. **Is there any way to stop the inner, malformed HTML from screwing up the alignment of the entire document that comes after the HTML?**

I realize that intelligently parsing it is one option (since I do have it on the server side), but I'm looking for a lighter solution.

**Edit** I know I could just replace the `<` and `>` with entities, but I want to keep the formatting (within reason).

Comment: I had a similar issue where users pasting Word content into a RADEdit control. The backing database field was not big enough and Word content was horrible Word-HTML. The page broke at the spot the half < tag was there. Instead as a fix we prevented saving when the content was bigger than the field. One option we initially pursued was wrapping the malformed HTML in a frame tag. and let the browser figure it out, and prevent the malformed html from messing layout. but frames need touch a side of the screen so we ended with no save if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @ggonsalv I thought about the Iframe tag, but then you need to provide another page that actually produces each the inner HTML...  meaning src is the only way to go, right?

Comment: Not that it's prohibitive, really...

Comment: @ggonsalv, put that as an answer, would you please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite you looking for a 'lighter solution' than HTML parsing, you might want to consider using [**HTML Purifier**](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or [**HTML Tidy**](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/), since that should take care of broken tags for you - that's essentially what they were made for.

Comment: Could be. I was kind of hoping for a cheesy HTML solution, but I'll see which of these is easiest in Ruby, too. Thanks!

Comment: I imagine **HTML Tidy** would be easier to call from Ruby, but I have no Ruby experience at all. Whatever you do, though, good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks @pinkgothic, since this problem was a one-off, I decided to just stip the `<` and `>`, but I was curious if there's something about HTMl that I don't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the inline text to support HTML? If not, you could just strip all HTML tags, or replace `<>` with escapes. Or you could store the text on the server as Markdown or any other non-HTML language and generate good HTML on the fly.

**Edit**: If you really need HTML, I suggest that you run an XML validator on the HTML snippet. You don't actually need to look at the structure of the XML: if the snippet is well-formed then it's very unlikely that it will break the rest of the layout.

Comment: Yes, it has to support HTML, sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<` and `>` with ascii/unicode equivalents `&#60;` and `&#62;` OR `&lt;` and `&gt;` OR `\u003c` and `\u003e`

Comment: Sorry, I can see the question wasn't clear. I could do that, but I want to keep the formatting if possible. Editing the question.